# Csv Helper no more setters in v22?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I use CsvReader occasionally; when upgrading from v18 to the latest v22 via NuGet I found breaking changes but it's not clear from the CsvReader's site how to fix breaking changes. Does anyone know how to provide equivalent functionality in CsvHelper v22 to do this code from v18:

```
using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyMap>(); //I believe this should now be csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<MyMap>(); 
    csv.Configuration.HeaderValidated = null; //broken - no setter on IReaderConfiguration
    csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null; //broken - no setter on IReaderConfiguration
}
```

The examples on CsvHelper website, StackOverflow and the documentation still reference old v18 setters so I can't find the way around it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're init-only properties, so they can still be set in an initializer:

```
var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    HeaderValidated = ... ,
    MissingFieldFound = ...
};

using (var csv = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(reader, conf))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<SomeMap>();
}
```

There's also a massive constructor with a bunch of optionals, you could pick them out :

```
var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  headerValidated: ...,
  missingFieldFound: ...
);
```

The constructor signature seems to indicate they'll end up null by default if this constructor is used and nothing is spec'd for them..

[image]

..but then there was [one recent related issue](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1673) with this constructor because `null` cannot be supplied to mean "take no action" because it's the default value used to indicate "no value was supplied" (and I'm not sure if a optional delegate can ever be anything else tbh) so any `null` you pass in is effectively ignored and the default function in ConfigurationFunctions.cs is used..

The suggested workaround is to supply a "does-nothing" delegate if you want to use the constructor form and want "no action" to arise:

```
var conf = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
  headerValidated: (_,_) => { },
  missingFieldFound: (_,_,_) => { }
);
```

Personally I'd use the initializer form

Comment: The constructor only exists because VB.NET doesn't have the ability to use `init`. Also, the null parameters are there to allow you to use named parameters. If null, they'll default, which is why you need to set an no-op delegate for the delegates instead of null.

Comment: @joshclose curious what the rationale was behind making them init rather than set? Does it cause a problem if they're changed at some time later than initialization? For it to clobber VB seems like a reasonable drawback; just wonder what the offsetting gain was?

Comment: Would an alternative strategy such as making them settable only once/settable upto some point on the usage timeline such as "first read/write" make sense?

Comment: I didn't know it was going to do that in VB.NET. That surprised me. It worked in C# all the way back to `net45` in my builds and I didn't think the compiler would generate IL that can't be used in VB.NET. I added the constructor after to allow VB.NET users to still use it. The reason behind making the config a read only `record` was to solve threading issues people were having when using one config in many readers/writers at the same time...

Comment: All the values of the config are copied locally, so I could make them settable. The issue I was trying to avoid was having people make changes to the config after it's passed into the constructor and not seeing those changes applied in the system. Maybe that would be less confusing anyways.

Comment: "having people make changes to the config after it's passed into the constructor and not seeing those changes applied in the system" When using a struct it should be clearer that changes afterwards won't have any effect.

Comment: How do I set CultureInfo afterwards when the ctor already created the CsvConfiguration instance? It can be only set by ctor. Setter has been removed. It is also no option for me to make the configuration itself settable, as I would also need to set all delegates, which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version for MissingFieldFound is

```
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
    MissingFieldFound = args =>

    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Missing field found at index {args.Index} with header '{args.HeaderNames}'");
    }
};
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
...
}
```